# Json-server store data to db.json

Tags: json, json-server

Im trying to post a object to create a new user to my vite project.
I use json-server for this project.
How can i store the data from post methods into my db.json file?

```
server.post("/api/users", (req, res) => {
      const { username, password, type, firstname, lastname, status } = req.body;
      const users = router.db.get("users");
      const user = users.find({ username }).value();
    
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
      }
    
      const newUser = {
        id: users.length + 1,
        username,
        password,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        status,
        type,
      };
    
      // Update the users in the database
      router.db.get("users").push(newUser).write();
    
      // Respond with the updated data
      res.status(201).json({
        token: generateCustomToken(newUser.id, newUser.username, newUser.type),
        user: { id: newUser.id, username: newUser.username, type: newUser.type },
      });
    });
```